# How textview work like as textfield?

Tags: iphone

I am developing one app, in that app I use TextView to enter the data.

How to quit the TextView and resign the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this delegate method with return key deduction to resign textview.see here

make sure u have

```
   urTextView.delegate=self;
```

and in ur viewcontroller.h file

```
  @interface urViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate> {


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
 replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
        // Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
            // Be sure to test for equality using the "isEqualToString" message
        [textView resignFirstResponder];

            // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
        return NO;
    }
        // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I want more that one line of text.If iam using this then i get only one line of text.How to did that

Comment: while user type in textview it will automatically wrap the word to next line if not space in current line.so just test it and then ........

Answer (score 2):

**For resign the keyboard of text-view you have to handle the delegate method of UITextview.**

**Below is the code for resign the keyboard of UITextview.**

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I want more that one line of text.If iam using this then i get only one line of text.How to did that

Comment: Wow - is this still the case --- I mean having to trap '\n' ? ... if so, what a HACK APPLE has left us with !